# Activists are calling for action after a huge escape of farmed fish in lceland risks devastating local salmon populations

Tags: meaning-in-context

> You're talking about the future of wild salmon'
> Activists are calling for action **after** a huge escape of farmed fish in lceland **risks** devastating local salmon populations.
> Suspected escapees have been found in at least 32 rivers across north-west Iceland, according to unconfirmed social media posts.
> Iceland's Marine and Freshwater Research Institute (MRI) confirmed the farmed fish have been found in multiple rivers.

Source: The Guardian https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2023/sep/30/thousands-of-salmon-escaped-an-icelandic-fish-farm-the-impact-could-be-deadly

---

I think that "**after**" does not fit the context, because a huge escape of farmed fish in iceland has not finished risking devastating local salmon population.
What do you say?

Comment: I don't get all these questions questioning publications like The Guardian. It's fine.  It's about devastating them, not finishing devasting them.

Comment: The escape has finished though, referring to the breaking out from the fish pens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The risk was instantly incurred by local salmon populations upon the escape of the farmed fish. Then (i.e. **after** the escape and its ongoing risk became known) activists called for action.

**After** requires a point-in-time event but the event doesn't need to be completed; it merely needs to have a starting point.

The verb in the clause can be in the simple present:

> City authorities  are shoring up the levee *after* two days of torrential rain *threaten* a breach.

You could put the verb in the present perfect:

> City authorities  are shoring up the levee *after* two days of torrential rain *have threatened* a breach.

Or you could underscore the incipience with "now":

> City authorities  are shoring up the levee *after* two days of torrential rain *now threaten* a breach.

but it isn't necessary. I think very few native speakers would find the simple present jarring in such situations where **after** is used with an incipient condition.

Comment: Could the "**risks**" in the original post be substituted with "has risked"?

Comment: @Englishgood Yes, you could replace simple present **risks** with present perfect **has risked** (analogous to my **have threatened** example). The perfect would mean that the risk has been incurred, not that the risk is finished and no longer in effect. If a gambler has put all of his money on the table, he **has risked** everything.

Answer (score 1):

"After" relates the time of the protests to the time of the release.

The release has finished, and the protests began after that (and naturally in response to it)

The use of "after" is correct and and natural in this position.

On the other hand the risks are ongoing.  "Risks" could be replaced by "is risking", but the rather terse style of news journalism would favour the simple tense.

Comment: We would get: "Activists are calling for action after a huge escape of farmed fish in lceland **is risking** devastating local salmon" Is that sentence fine?

Comment: Not so great actually... But "Activists are calling for action after a huge escape of farmed fish in lceland which is risking devastating local salmon" would work.